# How to compress audio and image files in Android?

Tags: android, compression

I store my audio files in the `raw` folder and image files in `drawable`. Each audio file takes about 300kb, images 50-100kb. The final version of the app will contain about 300 of audio files and about 1000 images. My question is how to compress them as much as possible? The app should work offline so I can't store the files somewhere in web.

Comment: It depends on the type of file how much it can be zipped if that is what you mean with 'compressed'. Pretty unclear.

Comment: All those files will automatically be zipped in the .apk. So what is it what you try to accomplish?

Comment: @greenapps I want to know the best practice to shrink size of the final app by reducing size of audio and image files.

Comment: `the final app` What is that? The final .apk?

Comment: @greenapps What I meant with this was installed apk. Maybe I use wrong terminology.

Comment: How would you determine the size of an installed .apk? And why would trying to make the final .apk as small as possible not be enough?

Comment: I really wonder what you are asking. If you want your app to occupy  less memory then add smaller files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Android Documentation you can read the APK is a compress format, so you dont need to compress all images, maybe you need to save the images and sound in SD CARD.

Can you imagine compress and decompress the image and sound every moment you need? maybe the performance no will be the best. Can you imagine the videogames? They have a lot of resource, the user should know if prefered download the resources of save in memory or SD data.

Answer (score -1):

compress Image : 'Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(capturedImage, width, height, true);'